# C# get string name's name

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get variable name using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566101/how-to-get-variable-name-using-reflection)

How to get the string name's name not the value of the string

```
string MyString = "";
Response.Write(MyString.GetType().Name);//Couldn't get the string name not the value of the string
```

The result should display back the string name "MyString"

I've  found some suggested codes and rewrite it to make it shorter but still didn't like it much.

```
static string VariableName<T>(T item) where T : class
{
    return typeof(T).GetProperties()[0].Name;
}
```

Response.Write(VariableName(new { MyString }));
I am looking another way to make it shorter like  below but didn't how to use convert the current class so i can use them in the same line

```
  Response.Write( typeof(new { MyString }).GetProperties()[0].Name);
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. An answer will tell you why shortly.

Comment: You can use reflection, but is there a particular reason you want to do that?

Comment: There are several ways to do it in this blog article: http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/13/how-to-find-out-variable-or-parameter-name-in-c.html

Comment: just want to make it easier to rename dynamic variable name HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(MyString)[MyString]

Answer (score 0):

While Marcelo's answer (and the linked to "duplicate" question) will explain how to do what you're after, a quick explanation why your code doesn't work.

[`GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) does exactly what it says: it gets the `Type` of the object on which it is called.  In your case, it will return `System.String`, which is the `Type` of the object referenced by your *variable* `MyString`. Thus your code will actually print the `.Name` of that `Type`, and not the name of the variable (which is what you actually want.)

Comment: I've made the class to be a lot shorter but I don't really like it much.
 static string VariableNameName<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperties()[0].Name;
    }
///Here is how to use it
 var MyString = "";
  Response.Write(VariableNameName(new { MyString }));

I wanted to make it shorter like the following but don't know how to use this LINQ yet. 
 Response.Write( typeof(new { MyString }).GetProperties()[0].Name);