# C# Variable Name To String

Tags: c#

I have variable

```
public string MyVariable;
```

I need use name of variable as string. Example:

```
var a = MyVariable.NameVariable();
// a = "MyVariable"
```

How i may to do this?

I would like to create your miniORM (NHibernate is too heavy and requires a separate library). At the moment the problem is that I have to point out a bunch of constants. For example:

```
public const string FieldIdRules = "idRules"
```

And then to make transactions in relation samonapisannom profiler.
I saw that Hibernate does not need to specify the text value (for the ratio of fields). I want to implement the same.

Sorry my bad english

Comment: This Stack Overflow answer might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566101/how-to-get-variable-name-using-reflection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566101/how-to-get-variable-name-using-reflection

thanks Aaron Blenkush8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hacky approach, you can get via `Expression`:

```
string myVariable = string.Empty;
Expression<Func<object>> expression = () => myVariable;

string name = (expression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
```

Comment: And it will tell you at compile-time if the name is changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access a variable by name, you already have its name, so type `"MyVariable"`.

If you’ve reassigned it, this is not possible. Values don’t keep a history of variable names somewhere.

---

So in order to handle field to column mappings, I would suggest a `Dictionary`. Reflection is a possibility, but is needlessly complicated for a simple task like that.