# Getting the name of a reference variable

Tags: c#

So,I have a class student and I created a reference variable pointing to the object of class student.I want to get the name of the reference variable in my code.I want o/p as Harry(which is my reference variable).Is this thing possible?

Code:

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

        namespace ConsoleApplication1
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    student harry = new student();
                    //OUTPUT:harry
                }
            }

            public class student { }
        }
```

Comment: add `public` to field definition

Comment: Do you want the name of the student or the name of the variable as its declared in the code.

Comment: As a side node, please take the time to read about C#'s conventions. For example, your class name should be written in PascalCase. It'll make it easier for everyone if you follow them, and it's easier to pick them up when you're learning the language.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I want the name of the reference variable i.e harry in the above code

Comment: can you provide sample what you want?

Comment: ... and _where_ exactly you want it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get variable name using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566101/how-to-get-variable-name-using-reflection)

Comment: ...and example why you want it... There could be much better way to achieve your actual goal (unless it is an programming exercise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not a way to do this. You can only access data that are stored in a class.

What you can do is to compare references e.g.

```
 if( otherStudent == student ) {  }
```

In this case you test weather the variable `otherStudent` points to the same object as the variable `student` points to.

Answer (score 1):

Better use a public  property than a field and  and do it like this:

```
//Class

public class Student { public string Name { get; set; }}

//Instantiate class method 1:

Student harry = new Student() {Name = "Harry"};

//Instantiate class method 2:

Student harry = new Student();
harry.Name="Harry";


//get property output:


Console.WriteLine(harry.Name);
```

Comment: you use `property` instead field :-)

Comment: Yeah. Did it on purpose :). I guess is better but he can choose. The dynamic is the same

Comment: You have also changed the field to a property

Comment: @CarlosLanderas: I agree it's better to make it a property - but it's worth calling that out in your answer. You *claim* you're making the field public, but you're not.

Comment: Name of the reference variable in my code is "Harry".So,is there any library fn. possible in c# which can give me the o/p as "Harry".Just like if I want the object's class name I could have used System.GetType().Name.

Comment: @JonSkeet, tell me if I am wrong, I already corrected it but it's not named "PascalCase"?

Comment: @CarlosLanderas: Doh doh doh! Absolutely. Will delete the comment through embarrassment.