# Get object reference name as string c#

Tags: c#, object, reference

here`s a simple question:

I have something like this

```
       Youtube youtubeChannel = new Youtube();

       Console.WriteLine("youtubeChannel");
```

Instead hardcoding youtubeChannel in console, i want to get reference name as string and print it in console. Something like:

```
       Console.WriteLine(youtubeChannel.ToString());
```

And get result -> "youtubeChannel" in console.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get variable name using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566101/how-to-get-variable-name-using-reflection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [how it was done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566101/how-to-get-variable-name-using-reflection) and take note of the pitfalls too..

Comment: If you find this is a duplicate question, then please flag it as such. The link will appear automatically.