# C# Convert string to name of bool variable

Tags: c#, string, boolean

I trying to make something like that:

```
    // int counter; - this is changing in ther other parts of program
    bool abc1; bool abc2; bool abc3; bool abc4;

    if("abc" + counter == true)
    {
     //some code
    }
```

Anyway, I need to convert string and int to bool name. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean "convert string and int to bool name"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: your question is unclear, please describe in detail what you are trying to accomplish.  ("abc" + counter == true) will never evaluate to true and I am having a hard time understanding what you are attempting to accomplish

Comment: He's trying to form the name of a variable from a string and an int in order to reference that variable.  Possibly doable via reflection, but much better to use @sstan's approach.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566101/how-to-get-variable-name-using-reflection

Comment: the only method that I can see then is @sstan, why are you not able to use an array?

Comment: Are those bools **local** to a method?...or are they class level variables?

Answer (score 7):

Use an array instead:

```
bool[] abc;

// ...

if (abc[counter] == true) {
{
    // some code.
}
```

Comment: can't use array in me case. it is possible to convert string to bool name?

Comment: @user5081068 You can't take a value and just magically get it's variable name. Why can't you use arrays?

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't sound like a good idea, as it sounds like you want to do some reflection.  If you are going to allow yourself to go down that path, then I have a hard time believing that you can't use an array.

Comment: If you really cannot use arrays, the next best alternative is a long chain of `if` statements `if (abc1) { /* Some code /* }  if (abc2) { /* Some code /* }` etc.  Even if you can use reflection (depends on where abcN are defined), that is a bad path to walk down.

Comment: ok i will try to use array. thanks for help :)

Comment: SO peer pressure FTW :)