# C# Getting the name of the variable

Tags: c#

I have 5 string variables.
Then I put them into a list.

If there a way when looping through the list to the actual name of the string variable?

Comment: You can't restore local variables' names

Comment: You can use `Dictionary<string,string>` where key is var name and value is var value and iterate through Keys

Comment: What do you need the variable name for? what is it you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It might be possible by using `nameof` operator introduced in C# 6.0

Comment: string does not hold information of its variable name or any thing. its just a sequence of characters. you can use Tuple for example where second item holds name of variable.

Comment: Err... this sounds very unusual. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Dictionary<string,string>` and iterate it like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("var1", var1);
... //do it for all variables
foreach (var variable in dict.Keys)
{
    var varname = variable;
    var varvalue = dict[variable];
}
```

Key would be variable name, and value would be variable value

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. When adding string variable to  `List<string>`, only value of the variable stored in the list, not the variable name which is used to store value earlier.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you can see how you can do this. The question is about reflection, but the accepted answer is what you need.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566101/how-to-get-variable-name-using-reflection)

**Edit:**

you can use expression trees and promote the variable to a closure:

```
static string GetVariableName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    var body = (MemberExpression)expr.Body;

    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

You can use the method like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var someVar = 3;

    Console.Write(GetVariableName(() => someVar));
}
```

And finally, you can do it this way with C# 6:

```
static void Main()
{
    var someVar = 3;

    Console.Write(nameof(someVar));
}
```

Still, I don't know what is the reason for doing this. If you need to keep the variable name as a key, do it like @wudzik sugested.

Comment: if you add link to question, maybe it's better to add link to original question rather than duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121/finding-the-variable-name-passed-to-a-function-in-c-sharp

Comment: @wudzik while the question is duplicate, I find it more convincing, I will take this advice anyways. Thank you.