# get a value from data (not list or dictionary)

Tags: c#, getvalue

Sorry im newb and I don't know how to ask my question properly in the title. I have a database:

```
class PlayerData
    {
        public ulong id;
        public string name;
        public int kills;
        public int deaths;
    }
```

and I want to return the value corresponding to the requested key

```
object getStats(ulong uid, string stat)
    {
        var player = BasePlayer.FindByID(uid);
        PlayerData data = PlayerData.Find(player);

        object value = data.TryGetValue(stat); // I know this ain't right

        return value;
    }
```

example:

```
int kills = getStats(123456, kills); //will ask for the value of "kills" in the data. Return data.kills
```

stat could be anything in data (id, name, kills, deaths)

thanks alot!

Comment: Does [something like this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2566177/1790644)?

Comment: How about using switch. For example

object TryGetValue(string stat)
{
       object returnValue=null;

       switch(stat)
       {
          case "name":
                   returnValue=name;
               break;
          case "kills":
                  returnValue=kill;
               break;
       }

       return returnValue;
}

Answer (score 0):

You could take Sun Maung Oo's suggestion of using a switch statement:

```
object TryGetValue(int playerId, string name)
{
    var player = GetPlayer(playerId);
    switch (name)
    {
        case "name": return name;
        case "kills": return kills;

        // Other properties
        // ...

        default: return null;
    }
}
```

Or you could flatten the data:

```
public class Statistic
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then finding the value is a matter of finding the statistic with the given player id and name.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are trying to do here is to get the object value base on the object Name? If that is the case, I think you could use reflection to achieve that. You could reference this answer: [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Sample Code:

```
class PlayerData
{
    public ulong id;
    public string name;
    public int kills;
    public int deaths;
}

object getStats(ulong uid, string stat)
{
    var player = BasePlayer.FindByID(uid);
    PlayerData data = PlayerData.Find(player);

    object value = data.GetType().GetProperty(stat).GetValue(data, null);

    return value;
}
```