# How to automatically put in the tag the name of the UIElement

Tags: c#, tags, uielement

I know that this might seems very strange but I have the need to automatically put in the tag the name of a graphic Element
e.g.

```
var tbkMain = new TextBlock(){Foreground = ...,..., Tag = ??? } <----here I wish automatically Tag= "TbkMain"

var grdSmall = new TextBlock(){Foreground = ...,..., Tag = ??? } <----here I wish automatically Tag= "grdSmall"
```

also something done afterwards like

```
tbkMain.Tag = ???;
```

or (and even better):

```
foreach(var element in grdMain.Children)
      element.Tag = ???
```

Thanks

I have to admit I do not even know if that is possible or where to start from.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566101/how-to-get-variable-name-using-reflection) you can see that nameof is what you need.

Therefore for example:

```
tbkMain.Tag = nameof(tbkMain);
```

but that is not very useful for it takes little to write tbkMain.Tag = "tbkMain"

As for the other chance in my book it is not possible for if you do:

```
foreach (UIElement item in grdAll.Children)
            item.Tag = nameOf(item);<----error
```

that is not possible for you have to define the type.
And even if you do:

```
foreach (UIElement item in grdAll.Children)
            {
                if (item is TextBlock) (item as TextBlock).Tag = nameof(item);
                if (item is StackPanel) (item as StackPanel).Tag = nameof(item);
                ...
            }
```

the result will be item and not the real name. Therefore useless.
Sorry...
`