# Array of objects: how to get names of objects inside array?

Tags: c#, reflection

For example, I have such method:

```
public void ExecuteExampleMethod()
{
    var exampleId1 = 1;
    var exampleId2 = 2
    ExampleMethod(0, exampleId1, exampleId2)
}

public void ExampleMethod(int exampleId, params object[] parameters)
{
   foreach(var parameter in parameters)
   {
     Console.WriteLine($"{parameter.Name} {parameter.Value}")
   }
   
}
```

So, I need to output like this:

```
"exampleId1 1"
"exampleId2 2"
```

How can I do it? I tried reflection = parameter.GetType() - but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: You can't get the variable name, since it's not part of the object. Why not use a `Dictionary<string,object>`?

Comment: You're going off down the wrong path. Objects don't have "names" based on the first variable that happened to reference them. In general, an object may be referenced from multiple locations (variables, contained in an array, etc) each of which has independent naming (or no naming, in the case of the array)

Comment: This sounds mightily like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: What would be the names if the method is called like this : `ExampleMethod(0, 1, 2);`?

Comment: @AtlasPromotion Another way is pass an tupple `(nameof(variable),value)` instead of the value only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter) and [How to get variable name using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566101/how-to-get-variable-name-using-reflection) and [How to check if the parameter of a method comes from a variable or a literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65754778/how-to-check-if-the-parameter-of-a-method-comes-from-a-variable-or-a-literal/65754971) and [Create dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/)

Answer (score -1):

Used Dictionary<string, object>.