# Is there a way to create a wrapper (or an alias) for the nameof operator in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using the `nameof` operator in C# quite often. So I'm wondering, is there a way to create a shorter version (a wrapper or an alias) for this operator, like `_(Identifier)` instead of `nameof(Idenfier)`.
More details:
I need to create long array of string like `var columns = new[] { nameof(Property1}, nameof(Property2), ... }`.
I'd like to make the code a bit shorter like `var columns = new[] { _(Property1), _(Property2) ...}`.
Is there a feature in C# to make this posible?

Comment: Static read-only string FTW...

Comment: Maybe you can achieve desired result with code generation or runtime reflection?

Comment: Are you trying to make the code itself shorter or are you trying to type less? If the latter then you should be aware that VS allows you to type the same text on multiple lines at the same time. If you hold the *Alt* key down while dragging the mouse, you can select an arbitrary block of text. You can select a block with zero width and multiple lines in height, then type `nameof()` once and that will appear on every line. You can then just type in the property names one by one. That trick with the *Alt* key is how you should select code in VS to copy here, so you can trim leading whitespace.

Comment: You could use [NimbleText](https://nimbletext.com/) to generate them. Make a  list of properties, write a little template to generate the `nameof` clauses, then paste that in

Answer (score 1):

**you CANT do that!**

even if you could, with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2566177/15204250):

```cs
private static string N(Expression<Func<object>> expr) => ((MemberExpression)expr.Body).Member.Name;
```

it wouldn't really be efficient considering it's usage:

```cs
var name = N(() => myVariable);
```

and also anything like this would be slow,

because once you compile your code with `nameof()` it will put your name like a normal string, consider this example:

```cs
var myname = "awdawda";
1.Console.WriteLine(nameof(myname));
2.Console.WriteLine(N(() => myname));
```

for line 1, generated IL is this:

```cs
    IL_0012: ldstr        "myname"
    IL_0017: call         void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_001c: nop
```

just a normal string at compile time,but if you look at line 2 you'll see this:

[image]

can you see the **mess** it just create for a single name ?

with all been said, I suggest you keep working with `nameof()`, or create some sort of source generator to make the work for you , that would be even harder to achieve.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this before posting the question. I know that drawback. It does not suite my need. I think a code snippet may be better to quickly input.